# Adjust width of container to child only using multiples of a number

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to use only CSS to adapt a container width to its child element content (the content is dynamic and load from the backend) but then adjusting this width to always a multiple of 8px. Is that possible only using CSS? (No JavaScript)

Thanks!

Edit: I'm trying to use the padding as a way to increase the width of the element and keeping the width:fit-content tag. The thing is, how can I get the current width of the element in CSS to create a formula that increases the padding to a multiple of 8? Can you come up with another solution? Thanks again. Example:

HTML

```
<div class="banner">This is a banner!</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: calc() /* Not sure what to do here */ 
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Did you search for `calc` in CSS?

Comment: @Muhammedogz and what exactly would you use `calc` _on_ here? Calc can't "access" the width of the child element, to base any calculation on that. I don't think there is any CSS-only solution for this very specific requirement.

Comment: Hi ! I bet it is possible ;) Please let us see an example of the rendered html page, and the css rules you tried to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I edited my question adding more details.

Comment: Thanks ! Please make a snippet in your question, it give better results than ocr on a screenshot ;)

Answer (score 1):

George if you have a codepen URL to attach it would be really helpful, and a photo of the expected result.

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20em;
}

.item {
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

this would work with reference to its parent container https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content